# Selenium Webdriver C# Random SelectByIndex from a Dropdown

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have a WebElement which is a dropdown. If I were to select an index from the dropdown list I would use the following code

```
SelectElement s = new SelectElement(ddlWebElement)
s.SelectByIndex(12);
```

What syntax would I used to instead of calling a specific index I wanted to randomly generate the selection each time.

UPDATE I tried this code but now i need to figure out how to narrow down the integer selection

```
Random r = new Random();
SelectElement s = new SelectElement(ddlChooseStore_Cart);
s.SelectByIndex(r.Next());
```

Comment: Generate an random integer within the range of indexes?

Comment: what is `SelectElement`

Comment: see my latest answer which will generate random number between 0 to 12 and using this you can select value index between 0 to 12 randomly, you can use any range, I have show just 0 to 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is replace the magic number `12` with random number. your code for this will like the following:

```
Random rnd = new Random(); // this can be global
SelectElement s = new SelectElement(ddlWebElement);
int itemCount= s.Items.Count(); // get the count of elements in ddlWebElement
s.SelectByIndex(rnd.Next(0,itemCount));// will give you random selections
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to select value between 0-12 index number then this will select value by random index

```
SelectElement s = new SelectElement(ddlWebElement)
Random rnd = new Random();
int index = rnd.Next(0, 12);
s.SelectByIndex(index);
```